# Identification of military uniform, probably French or Italian

Tags: identification, uniform, italian, french

I'm trying to ID someone's military uniform in an old family photo. Not a lot of clues to go on, except that the man was probably French or Italian, maybe in a colonial setting. Perhaps someone can recognize the insigna on the cap.

[image]

Tried to look it up myself but didn't have any luck. Thanks if you have anything to contribute.

Comment: The cap is definitely Italian.

Comment: Badge appears to be a regimental badge of an Italian type. It has a Savoy crown on top with crossed rifles and crossed powder horns. Subject is obviously a child but presumably from a wealthy family that could afford a mini Italian uniform made for him.